# Where to place external .js file in aspx page that uses master file

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

I've got an aspx page that inherits from a master page template.  Usually, I'd place the link to my external javascript file inside of the `<head>` element of the html page, but the `<head>` element is in the master page.

Where should I place the reference to my external .js page?

If I try to just put a `<script>` tag below the `<%@ Page %>` element, I get some error saying that I must place tags inside of `<asp:content>` sections.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put it in one of the content panels in your content page e.g

```
 <asp:content runat="server" id="content1" contentplaceholderid="cp1">
     <script type="text/javascript" src="somepath"></script>
    </asp:content>
```

Comment: Is there some order that the content panels are added to a site? If I remember correctly, people recommend adding the javascript in with the head element so that the js file is loaded before the page content or something like that. Is there any advantage to one content panel over another?

Comment: Just in order.  There should be a contentplaceholder in the head of your master page.  if not create one there and then create a content panel in your content page that references the contentplaceholder like in my code above.

Answer (score 1):

Create a placeholder in the header of the master page, and add the script to that placeholder on the page.

Master:

```
<head runat="server">
    <title>My Appplication</title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" />
</head>
```

Page:

```
<asp:Content ID="PageHeaderContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeaderContent" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="somejsfile.js"></script> 
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Won't that import the file onto EVERY page that inherits from the master? I only need the external file on this one page

Comment: No, only the pages you add it to.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you want the script on your child page, not in the master page template.  In that case, you need a content placeholder in the `<head>` element of your master page.  Then use the `<asp:content>` tags on your child page and place the reference to your external javascript there.  I wouldn't be surprised, if your master page already has a content placeholder in its `<head>` tags.

Comment: i think by default it creates one

Answer (score 0):

Inside of your master page's `<body> .. <form> ..` add the `asp:ScriptReference` tag into your `asp:ScriptManager`, *not in the content* :

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="scripty" runat="server">
        <Scripts>
            <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/Timer/myJsFile.js"></asp:ScriptReference>
        </Scripts>
    </asp:ScriptManager>
```

If you want to lead it from the client side you will need to add somewhere in your page's `<body>` or `content`:

```
<script>
    window.onload: start;
</script>
```

Alternatively, for each page `aspx.cs` that needs it, I use this on the server side:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "Start", "window.onload=Start;", true);
```

Where in my javascript file I have:

```
function Start() {
...
}
```

Tip: `ScriptManager` is widely used by large Js libraries like jQuery.

Within your javascript, if you have jQuery installed, you can call any ASP object, that has `ClientIDMode="Static"`, within the master page with `$("#nameOfObject")`.

I am *not sure* if the above process works with content pages, so the object may have to be on the master page.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to Create a placeholder in the header of the master page, and add the script to that placeholder on the page.

In Master page :-

```
<head runat="server">
     <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
```

In Content page(aspx page) :- give the scripts and source of the JavaScript path like below.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    <%-- <b> Trailing Target/Sl</b>--%>
     <!-- jQuery library -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Popper JS -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="atjavascript/custom.js"></script>
</asp:Content>
```