# How to add Autocomplete textbox in ASP.Net webform with masterpage using webmethod in .aspx.cs codebehind

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I want to add the autocomplete textbox in asp.net with masterpage using `WebMethod` and  my logic is not working well I have read this [autocomplete not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22669835/autocomplete-does-not-work-in-asp-net-webform-with-masterpage)  and  [external js file placement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8013200/where-to-place-external-js-file-in-aspx-page-that-uses-master-file/73645966#73645966) and I'm not sure where I did the mistake below is my code.

I have created simple master page

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Delete_auto.master.cs" Inherits="TradePages.Delete_auto" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And next I have added the webform with master page and added the related scripts and external js file path (I downloaded the jquery script links from [this](https://jqueryui.com/download/#!version=1.13.2&components=110000010001000000100000100000000000000000000000) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/ajax/cdn/overview#Using_ASPNET_Ajax_from_the_CDN_20)link)

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Delete_auto.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Delete_auto_text.aspx.cs" Inherits="TradePages.Delete_auto_text" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">

      <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.8.0.js"></script>
     <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.22/jquery-ui.js"></script>
     <link rel="Stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.10/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" />

    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="atjavascript/delete_auto.js"></script>

</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

    <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Enter ash to get fullname"></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtAutotext" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

</asp:Content>
```

And next I created the external JavaScript file and added the code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="atjavascript/delete_auto.js"></script>
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    ////textbox auto complete
    //txtAutotext
    $("#<%= txtAutotext.ClientID  %>").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            //debugger;
            var param = { text: $('#txtAutotext').val() };
            $.ajax({
                url: "Delete_auto_text.aspx/GetFirstNames",
                data: JSON.stringify(param),
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

                dataFilter: function (data) {
                    //document.getElementById("smblerror").style.display = "none";

                    return data;
                },

                success: function (data) {
                    //debugger;
                    if (data.d.length == 0) {

                        //document.getElementById("alterror").style.display = "";
                    }
                    else {

                        response($.map(data.d, function (item) {

                            document.getElementById("alterror").style.display = "none";
                            return {
                                value: item
                            }

                        }))
                    }

                },

                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(textStatus);
                }

            });
        },
        minLength: 3 //This is the Char length of inputTextBox    
    });

});
```

And next I used the simple WebMethod logic in codebehind

```
[WebMethod]
        public static string GetFirstNames(string text)
        {

            string name = "ash";
            string statusreturn = "";

            try
            {
                if (text == name)
                {
                    statusreturn = "Ashok";
                }
               

            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }

            return statusreturn;

        }
```

And next I have run this code and I didn't get any error and code is not executing

[image: Executing the project]

Suggest me how to achieve this and where I did the mistake.

Comment: did you inspect the web page , what error its showing in the console?

Comment: Hi @Sund'er tnx for your comment I have inspect the web page & I didn't get any error and code is not executing (nothing is happening).

Comment: why you are using 3 jquery files (jquery-1.8.0.js,1.8.3/jquery.min.js,3.5.1/jquery.min.js)?. Try to use the max full version?

Comment: I have modified the code and used the latest full version of jquery downloaded form [this](https://jqueryui.com/download/#!version=1.13.2&components=110000010001000000100000100000000000000000000000) link and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/ajax/cdn/overview#Using_ASPNET_Ajax_from_the_CDN_20) link but still not working well .

Comment: look into : https://stackoverflow.com/a/22670405/8843451

Comment: I have Included this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22669835/autocomplete-does-not-work-in-asp-net-webform-with-masterpage/22670405#22670405) in my question and I have worked as well  and I have read this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8013200/where-to-place-external-js-file-in-aspx-page-that-uses-master-file/73645966#73645966) also placing external js file still not working suggest me with your best solution tq.

Comment: Don't `stringify` the parameter. Instead type `data: param`. `stringify` use when you pass the object. Here you pass the only one simple string.